# Ruby CSV parser validator

Tags: ruby, parsing

I need help with writing Ruby CSV parser validator

I spent last night trying to write a Ruby CSV parser validator with the following functions

(1) Ruby function valid CSV parser with quoted fields

(2 )Ruby function validator for CSV parser to  handle delimited comma

(3) Ruby function validator for CSV parser to handle alternate separators

In my Rspec I defined this :

```
describe " tests" do
 it "inputs params" do
    expect(ashanti("12,22,33\n44,55,66", ",", "\"")).to eq([["12", "22", "33"], ["44", "55", "66"]])
  end
end
```

I am getting this error

```
An error occurred while loading spec_helper.
Failure/Error: require 'solution'

SyntaxError:
  /workspace/default/lib/ashanti.rb:4: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
    ("12,22,33\n44, 55,66", ",", "\"").scan(/((?:\\.|[^,...
                   ^
  /workspace/default/lib/ashanti.rb:4: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
    ("12,22,33\n44,55,66", ",", "\"").scan(/((?:\\.|[^,])*,?...
```

The  Ruby MRI interpreter is complaining of comma separator delimiter

I would need help in getting the CSV parser working

Comment: looks like you forgot to close a string somewhere in ashanti.rb

Comment: btw, ruby already includes a csv parser. Are you sure you want to write your own?

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev thanks for the info. My graduation requires, a Ruby CSV parser validator targeting

(1) Ruby function valid CSV parser with quoted fields

(2 )Ruby function validator for CSV parser to  handle delimited comma

(3) Ruby function validator for CSV parser to handle alternate separators


Do you have documentations I can read, i really need help with it